# Conditional probability table from deterministic relationships of two discetizied distributions - for Bayesian Networks

Tags: bayesian, conditional-probability, bayesian-network

Consider a simple Bayesian Network of three variables A, B, and C. All of the variables are discrete variables between (0,1] *that are discretized* as below:

`Ψ (A,B,C) : {(0,0.2], (0.2–4], (0.4–0.6], (0.6–0.8],(0.8–1]}`

I Know A and B are discretized Truncated Normal distributions with a mean of 0.4, and variance of 0.1; such as:

`A, B ~ TNormal{(0,1],0.4,0.1}`

And I know that C is a *deterministic function of the two distributions* e.g. is an average of the two, with the same variance.

`C ~ TNormal{(0,1],(A+B)/2,0.1}`

How can I calculate the CPT for node C, from A, and B, that creates the same relation? I know some commercial software create those. But I do not know how, and I want to incorporate that in my `BNlearn` graph so that it can work as part of the back propagation of evidence.

[image]

Comment: What do you mean by your first formula with $\Psi$?

Comment: That they are discretized as such, in 0.2 intervals.

Comment: If they are discretized, then they cannot follow truncated normal distributions, because they are continuous distributions. So the statement is contradictory.

Comment: Well, you can discretize the truncated normal distribution as well for the intervals. This only helps to come up with CPTs to use general BN algorithms.

Comment: You don't need to discretize anything. Do you have any data, because your don't mention any?

Comment: I agree, but this is to create a program where they can asses risk based on categorial factors, and then combine those factors, using a discrete Bayesian network, and with junction tree type algorithms.One  can code in the combination anyway. But I know some software are translating those into CPTs. I was wondering how that is being done.

Comment: Do you have any data? What do you mean by "CPT"?

Comment: Conditional Probability Tables for the nodes. No, I have no data, I only have parameters for TNormal as I mentioned based on "expert knowledge".

Comment: Why did you delete your question?

Comment: I think I kinda worked out the answer. The answer is to discretize the deterministic function of the two for each state of the `C|A,B`. It seemed pretty easy all of a sudden, but I am not sure, I will check this and report here.

Answer (score 1):

You have three random variables

$$\begin{align}
A &\sim \mathcal{TN}_{(0, 1)}(0.4, 0.1) \\
B &\sim \mathcal{TN}_{(0, 1)}(0.4, 0.1) \\
C &\sim \mathcal{TN}_{(0, 1)}(\tfrac{A+B}{2}, 0.1) \\
\end{align}$$

Given your diagram, you seem to assume independence between $A$ and $B$, so the distribution of $C$ is

$$
f(c|a,b) = \mathcal{TN}_{(0, 1)}(c \mid \tfrac{a+b}{2}, 0.1) \cdot \mathcal{TN}_{(0, 1)}(a \mid 0.4, 0.1) \cdot \mathcal{TN}_{(0, 1)}(b \mid 0.4, 0.1)
$$

where to calculate cumulative probabilities, you just need to calculate integrals, e.g.

$$
\Pr(C<c) = \int_{-\infty}^\infty \int_{-\infty}^\infty \int_{-\infty}^c f(c|a,b) \;da\,db\,dc
$$

To calculate it, you need an algorithm for automatic integration, they are commonly implemented in many software packages. You can use grid approximation as well, but with just five points, as you proposed, you would loose so much information, that it would be a very rough approximation. On another hand, with more detailed grid, this would become more computationally intensive then simple Monte Carlo simulation.

In fact, Monte Carlo sampling is the simplest and most flexible approach. To calculate the quantities of interest, you would draw a lot of samples from the distributions $A$ and $B$, and conditionally on them, from $C$, and then use the estimated statistics from the Monte Carlo samples.

```r
library(extraDistr)
set.seed(42)
n <- 1000000

A <- rtnorm(n, 0.4, 0.1, 0, 1)
B <- rtnorm(n, 0.4, 0.1, 0, 1)
C <- rtnorm(n, (A+B)/2, 0.1, 0, 1)
```

Given such samples, you can easily calculate the statistics of interest, e.g. $E[C\mid A<0.3, B<0.2]$ would be

```r
mean(C[A < 0.3 & B < 0.2])
## 0.209704025516417
```

and $\Pr(C<0.3\mid A <0.1, B < 0.2)$ would be

```r
mean(C[A < 0.1 & B < 0.2] < 0.3)
## 0.967741935483871
```

or $\Pr(C < 0.4)$

```r
mean(C < 0.4)
## 0.499649
```

etc.

Comment: Thanks a lot @Tim for your answer. This seems to solve the problem on a much better basis.

Comment: I got a question @Tim, what if I want the following quantity 
`Pr( 0.4<C<0.6 ∣ 0.2<A<0.4, 0.6<B<0.8)`, the `mean` seems not working.

Comment: @PitPartizan what exactly is not working?

Comment: I think the `mean` command is only calculating the mean for the one tailed cumulative probability, but regardless, could you review the R syntax for `Pr( 0.4<C<0.6 ∣ 0.2<A<0.4, 0.6<B<0.8)` with me here? how do you get that in R. thanks a lot @Tim !

Comment: @PitPartizan mean(0.4 < C & C < 0.6) etc